# Inkscape - circle filled with stripes

Tags: inkscape

[image]

I have white circle and 3 stripes at the back: blue, violet and yellow. I want to have this white circle to have background with those 3 stripes like this:

[image]

I've tried path -> difference and other path option, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Zyg, Have you considered to use a three colors [gradient](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Bucket-SimpleUse.html)? Else, if your starting stripes are three objects, you need to apply on each the difference (you need three circles) in order to obtain the desired result. Please, try and update us on your efforts.

Comment: have you checked the [clip tool](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-what-are-clipping-and-masking-in-inkscape--vector-24947)?

Comment: Shall your result have this blur effect? What's about the black border? Or is this just a sketching?

Answer (score 1):

To use the Inkscape **clip tool** select both, the clip mask, and the background

[image]

After that clip the background to the clip mask with *Object > Clip > Set*:

[image]

Note that filter effects or blur will only work on the background but not on the clip mask.